# Continuity, sequential continuity and the subspace topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X\subset \mathbb R^n$. I am tasked with showing that a function $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is continuous w.r.t. the subspace topology iff for every sequence $\{x_n\}\in X$ converging to $x\in X, \lim f(x_n) = f(x).$ My attempt (for one direction): for any neighborhood $U$ of $f(x)$ there exists a neighborhood $V\subset X$ of $x$ with $f(V)\subset U$. Since $x_n \to x$ there exists $N$ such that $x_n\in V$ for $n>N$, forcing $f(x_n)\in U$ for $n>N.$
Questions:

1. Is this correct?
2. How do I show the reverse direction?
3. Is there another way using the fact that $f = \tilde{f}\circ i,$ with $i:X\to \mathbb R^n$ the inclusion mapping (which is continuous)?
4. Assuming this result, how can I then construct a discontinuous function $f:C \to \mathbb R$ where $C$ is the Cantor set?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the forward direction is correct. It holds in any topological space, not just subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ or metric spaces.

For the other direction we can use a property of metric spaces: a set $C$ is closed iff all sequences from $C$ that converge in $X$ have their limit in $C$.

With this we can show that $f^{-1}[C]$ is closed for any closed $C \subseteq \Bbb R$ and the sequential continuity of $f$. So normal continuity then follows.